# What does Windows 7 use to encrypt passwords?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, encryption

Like what hash algorithm does it use? XP used DES for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the password for the Windows user accounts they use [NTLMv2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLMv2#NTLMv2).

Keep in mind, that normally, passwords are not encrypted, they are hashed.